# Bind Entity List thru Json

Tags: json

I have an HTML table like.

```
foreach (Entities.Customers each in Model.CustomerList)
        {
             <tr> 
               <td id="@each.Id" class="ppTableTd" >@each.Name</td>
             </tr>
        }
```

On Click event on an textbox, I will get an Id and depending upon that bind this particular table
Here is code: I am trying to bind this entity list thru JSON

```
var jsonData = new
            {
                CustomersList = customers
            };

return Json(jsonData, "text/json", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

How do I do this??